# MAXDOP setting as uneven number or number not divisible by 4

Tags: sql-server

One always sees maxdop as 4, 8 or 16. Is it recommended that maxdop is always divisible by 4? Is there e.g. a problem with setting maxdop as 12? Well 12 is also divisible by 4 but the result is an uneven number. So what about uneven numbers, e.g. 3, 5 or 9?

Please vote or comment on the answer below.  I do not have the knowledge to evaluate the answer.

Comment: There is no technical reason why or why not, just a love of base 2.  But you are the type of person who leaves time on the microwave without.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is probably easier to use the factors (or divisors) of the number of physical cores, or in the case of Hyperthreading the number of "available" cores to determine a valid MAXDOP setting.

If you have an Intel Processor with 12 cores then valid numbers for `max degree of parallelism` would be:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 6
- 12

This would allow a process to run certain index seeks or scans on the above number of cores in parallel. (Well not for 1 as this would stop processes from running in parallel.)

If you had two processes running on a `max_dop` setting of `6` and they went parallel, because of an index seek/scan, then they could conduct their seeks/scans each using 6 cores and at the same time. One process would not have to wait for the other process.

Setting the `max_dop` to seven would be a bad idea, because a statement that performed an index seek/scan in parallel, would be faster if it were to run on 7 cores, but the same index seek/scan could be less performant on the other available 5 cores.

#### Answering Your Questions

> Is it recommended that maxdop is always divisible by 4?

No. I would recommend to use the factors/divisors of the available cores / hyper-threaded cores.

> Is there e.g. a problem with setting maxdop as 12?

If you have only 12 (24, 36, 48) cores, then the answer would be no. However, on a 12 core processor (or a hyper-threaded 6 core processor), setting `max_dop` to 12 could hinder other smaller statements from executing fast, as they would be competing with the process (index seek/scan) that is running in parallel on the 12 cores.

And again having a max_dop setting of 12 on an 18 core processor would be similar to the situation with 5 and 7 on a 12 core processor.

> And what about uneven numbers, e.g. 5 or 9?

Well, if you have a 20 core processor, then 5 is a good number to go with. Same for 9 on a 18 core or 36 core processor.

Reference Reading

- [Intel 20 Core Processor Specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91753/intel-xeon-processor-e52698-v4-50m-cache-2-20-ghz.html)
- [Intel 18 Core Processor Specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/198017/intel-core-i910980xe-extreme-edition-processor-24-75m-cache-3-00-ghz.html)
- etc.

Comment: There is also NUMA nodes to factor in, even some single socket processors run internally as separate nodes, so you may want to divide by that also.

Comment: That would be a plus. I reckoned that could be left out for the moment. But, I wonder: somebody down-voted my answer, but left no alternate answer.